# Extracting Intermediate layer outputs of a CNN in PyTorch

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch, torchvision

I am using a `Resnet18` model.

```
ResNet(
  (conv1): Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(2, 2), padding=(3, 3), bias=False)
  (bn1): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
  (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
  (maxpool): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
  (layer1): Sequential(
    (0): BasicBlock(
      (conv1): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn1): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (conv2): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn2): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    )
    (1): BasicBlock(
      (conv1): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn1): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (conv2): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn2): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    )
  )
  (layer2): Sequential(
    (0): BasicBlock(
      (conv1): Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn1): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (conv2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn2): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (downsample): Sequential(
        (0): Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(2, 2), bias=False)
        (1): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      )
    )
    (1): BasicBlock(
      (conv1): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn1): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (conv2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn2): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    )
  )
  (layer3): Sequential(
    (0): BasicBlock(
      (conv1): Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn1): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (conv2): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn2): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (downsample): Sequential(
        (0): Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(2, 2), bias=False)
        (1): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      )
    )
    (1): BasicBlock(
      (conv1): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn1): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (conv2): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn2): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    )
  )
  (layer4): Sequential(
    (0): BasicBlock(
      (conv1): Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn1): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (conv2): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn2): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (downsample): Sequential(
        (0): Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(2, 2), bias=False)
        (1): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      )
    )
    (1): BasicBlock(
      (conv1): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn1): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (conv2): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (bn2): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    )
  )
  (avgpool): AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=(1, 1))
  (fc): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=1000, bias=True)
)
```

I want to extract the outputs only from `layer2`, `layer3`, `layer4` & I don't want the `avgpool` and `fc` outputs.
How do I achieve this ?

```
class BasicBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, stride=1, padding=1) -> None:
        super(BasicBlock, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels,
                               3, stride, padding=padding, bias=False)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(out_channels, out_channels,
                               3, stride=1, padding=1, bias=False)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels)
        if in_channels != out_channels:
            l1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels,
                           kernel_size=1, stride=stride, bias=False)
            l2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels)
            self.downsample = nn.Sequential(l1, l2)
        else:
            self.downsample = None

    def forward(self, xb):
        prev = xb
        x = self.relu(self.bn1(self.conv1(xb)))
        x = self.bn2(self.conv2(x))
        if self.downsample is not None:
            prev = self.downsample(xb)
        x = x + prev
        return self.relu(x)

class CustomResnet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, pretrained:bool=True) -> None:
        super(CustomResnet, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=7,stride=2, padding=3, bias=False)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(64)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
        self.maxpool = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1)
        self.layer1 = nn.Sequential(BasicBlock( 64, 64, stride=1), BasicBlock(64, 64))
        self.layer2 = nn.Sequential(BasicBlock(64, 128, stride=2), BasicBlock(128, 128))
        self.layer3 = nn.Sequential(BasicBlock(128, 256, stride=2), BasicBlock(256, 256))
        self.layer4 = nn.Sequential(BasicBlock(256, 512, stride=2), BasicBlock(512, 512))

    def forward(self, xb):
        x = self.maxpool(self.relu(self.bn1(self.conv1(xb))))
        x = self.layer1(x)
        x2 = x = self.layer2(x)
        x3 = x = self.layer3(x)
        x4 = x = self.layer4(x)
        return [x2, x3, x4]
```

I guess one solution would be this .. But is there any other way without writing this while lot of code? Also is it possible to load in the pre-trained weights given by `torchvision` in the above modified `ResNet` model.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you know how the `forward` method is implemented, then you can subclass the model, and override the `forward` method only.

If you are using the pre-trained weights of a model in PyTorch, then you already have access to the code of the model. So, find where the code of the model is, import it, subclass the model, and override the `forward` method.

For example:

```py
class MyResNet18(Resnet):

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

  def forward(self, xb):
    x = self.maxpool(self.relu(self.bn1(self.conv1(xb))))
    x = self.layer1(x)
    x2 = x = self.layer2(x)
    x3 = x = self.layer3(x)
    x4 = x = self.layer4(x)
    return [x2, x3, x4]
```

and you are done.

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, there is a pytorch utility to easily get intermediate results https://pypi.org/project/torch-intermediate-layer-getter/